# I can not access to FTP in Android

Tags: android

I am working on a project. My project first step connect to ftp. I read documentation and searched in stackoverflow but i did not find a solution. 
I am beginner for android developer. When run application i saw fatal errors below LogCat and java files.How can i fix that please help me this project very important for me.

logcat:

```
11-03 04:27:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 04:27:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(330): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient
11-03 04:27:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.example.cka.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
11-03 04:27:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
11-03 04:27:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
11-03 04:27:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-03 04:27:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-03 04:27:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-03 04:27:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-03 04:27:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 04:27:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-03 04:27:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-03 04:27:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-03 04:27:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 04:27:40.810: I/Process(330): Sending signal. PID: 330 SIG: 9
```

--

main activity:

```
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);        
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        core f = new core();
        f.mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
        f.ftpConnect("**.***.***.**", "****", "****", 21);
        try {
            tv.setText(f.ftpStatus());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    });
```

--

core.java

```
package com.example.cka;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.*;
import android.util.Log;

public class core {


    private static final String TAG = null;
    public FTPClient mFTPClient = null;

    public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username,String password, int port){

        try {
            mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
            // connecting to the host
            mFTPClient.connect(host, port);

            if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {
            boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);

            mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            return status;
            }
        }    

        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not connect to host " + host );
        }

        return false;
    }



    public boolean ftpDisconnect()
    {
        try {
            mFTPClient.logout();
            mFTPClient.disconnect();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error occurred while disconnecting from ftp server.");
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String ftpStatus() throws IOException{

            String status = mFTPClient.getStatus();
            return status;
    }       
}
```

Comment: have you given INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: yes i have one

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.apache.commons.net.ftp.*` doesn't seem to be included in the android APIs. Try adding the library to your project /libs folder.

EDIT: Is your FTP library included in the build path? Right-click on the project and go to Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries, click Add JARs, and add your library from the project's /libs folder. Then click on Order and Export and make sure it's checked to include it in your application when it is build.

Comment: Not quite. Adding the JAR to the /libs folder includes it in the project, but doesn't make it a part of the compiled .apk file. This tells Eclipse that the JAR should be exported with the .apk, so that Android can find the class when it's needed since its not part of the Android API.

Comment: I don't know which version of eclipse plugin you are using but this is not true for at least the past year. When you add a jar to libs the plugin adds it to the classpath automatically

Comment: Yes, but it didn't add it to the exports when I did that, so I had to do it manually.

Comment: In fact - jars you put in libs are supposed to show in not in the general classpath but under "Android Dependencies". If that is not happening in your case then there's something wrong with your setup. I would just try to regenerate the project

Answer (score 1):

Read the log output: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient`. Put your FTP library into the libs folder.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stack trace you are missing `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` class. Which probably means you are not including that library in your project. You should take the ftp client jar file and put it into project/libs directory

Comment: i have jar files are apache-commons-net.jar and commons-net-ftp-2.0.jar in the Referenced Libraires why still does not working i cant understand.